# How Regression Interpolation possible in R?

Tags: raster, rgdal

I have climatic data of different weather stations. I want to interpolate this data using regression instead of kriging or IDW. Can anyone tell how to do this in R?

Answer (score 2):

Some example data (you should have included that with your question)

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
ra <- aggregate(r, 10)
d <- na.omit(data.frame(v=values(ra), xyFromCell(ra, 1:ncell(ra))))
```

Fit a model

```
m <- glm(v ~ ., data=d)
```

Predict that to a raster

```
p <- raster(r)
p <- interpolate(p, m)
```

Remove unwanted areas

```
p <- mask(p, r)
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. This is really useful.